# Scala, passing a locally defined function into a list?

Tags: scala, programming-languages

I have not understood the following code snippet why `afterDelay(0) {...}`, a locally defined function can be stored into agenda? Can someone help me understand the `afterDelay(0) {...}` in the `run` function?

```
abstract class Simulation {

  type Action = () => Unit

  case class WorkItem(time: Int, action: Action)

  private var curtime = 0
  def currentTime: Int = curtime

  private var agenda: List[WorkItem] = List()

  private def insert(ag: List[WorkItem], item: WorkItem): List[WorkItem] = {
    if (ag.isEmpty || item.time < ag.head.time) item :: ag
    else ag.head :: insert(ag.tail, item)
  }

  def afterDelay(delay: Int)(block: => Unit) {
    val item = WorkItem(currentTime + delay, () => block)
    agenda = insert(agenda, item)
  }

  private def next() {
    (agenda: @unchecked) match {
      case item :: rest => 
        agenda = rest 
        curtime = item.time
        item.action()
    }
  }

  def run() {
    afterDelay(0) {
      println("*** simulation started, time = "+
          currentTime +" ***")
    }
    while (!agenda.isEmpty) next()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
afterDelay(0) {
    println(...)
}
```

Is equivalent to the following:

```
afterDelay(0)({
    println(...)
})
```

The function `afterDelay` is invoked a new `WorkItem` (`item`) is added to the list, not the function itself. The parameter **`block: => Unit` is a "By-Name Parameter"** (see the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) section 4.6.1): the expression used as the argument is implicitly converted into a "parameterless method" (*without* being evaluated first) that will be invoked whenever the variable inside the method is accessed (no `()` required).

In this case that is when the function resulting from `() => block` is *invoked*: it is invoked at `item.action()` which occurs at some point *after* the new `WorkItem` is added to the list (and `afterDelay` returns).

If it was written as (taking in a function paramater, not a by-name/thunk):

```
def afterDelay(delay: Int)(block: () => Unit) {   // take a function
  // new function will invoke function named by "block" when invoked ...
  val item = WorkItem(..., () => block())
  // or skip wrapping the function in a function ...
  // val item = WorkItem(..., block)
  ...
}
```

Then it would need to be invoked passing in a *function*:

```
afterDelay(0)(() => { // need a function
    println(...)
})
```

Or, alternative syntax, still a function of `() => Unit`, but the outside parenthesis can be avoided:

```
afterDelay(0) { () => // need a function
    println(...)
}
```

---

Extract from the SLS, 4.6.1 By-Name Parameters:

> The type of a value parameter may be preﬁxed by `=>`, e.g. `x: => T`. The type of such a parameter is then the parameterless method type `=> T`. This indicates that the corresponding argument is *not* evaluated at the point of function application, but instead is *evaluated at each use within the function*. That is, the argument is evaluated using call-by-name.

Comment: "Here that is when the function resulting () => block is invoked. Here that happens at some point after the afterDelay function returns (on item.action())." -- are you saying afterDelay is called during item.action()? I feel println("*** simulation started, time = "+ currentTime +" ***"), i.e., the ()=>Unit argument for afterDelay, is called during item.action()

Comment: No, `afterDelay` is invoked when it is invoked. It creates a *new* function object (that becomes the `WorkItem.action`) that closes over the `block` parameter (binds it in a closure). It then creates the new `WorkItem`, and queues it; when that *new* function is invoked (via `item.action()` elsewhere) then it will in turn cause the evaluation of the by-name parameter (which is what will invoke the `println`). Compare it with passing in a `() => Unit` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You defined afterDelay as a [curried function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). This means it has two parameter lists. In scala you can replace the brackets surounding the parameterlist `(...)` with `{...}`. In the second parameterlist you are using a ["call-by-name" parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-by-name#Call_by_name). Those parameters are evaluated everytime again you use them in your function. A good Example is [here](http://omgo.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/scala-call-by-name-vs-call-by-type/).

"Call-by-name" parameters are often used to define your own controlling structure.

```
def do(until: Int)(body: => Unit) {
  body
  if (until > 1) do(until - 1)(body)
}

do(0)(println("test"))
do(5)(println("test2"))
```

This is an example for a do until. It will print once `test` and five times `test2`.